# Update Trigger on Insert in AS400

Tags: sql, triggers, db2, ibm-midrange

I am trying to update a field of the current inserted row in AS400. I am using version 4.5, 5.3 and 7.1.

For my tests, I have created a table WC (Work Center) containing a CRTDT field (NUMERIC 7,0)
When inserting a new record to this table, I want to check if the value of this field is less that 200,000 and if yes add to it 1,000,000.

My SQL is:

```
--  Generate SQL 
--  Version:                    V5R4M0 060210 
--  Generated on:               10/13/16 10:03:49 
--  Relational Database:        S65BEE7B 
--  Standards Option:           DB2 UDB iSeries 
CREATE TRIGGER RAVONLIB.WC_TRIGGER 
    AFTER INSERT ON RAVONLIB.WC 
    FOR EACH STATEMENT 
    MODE DB2SQL 
    SET OPTION  ALWBLK = *ALLREAD , 
    ALWCPYDTA = *OPTIMIZE , 
    COMMIT = *NONE , 
    DECRESULT = (31, 31, 00) , 
    DFTRDBCOL = *NONE , 
    DYNDFTCOL = *NO , 
    DYNUSRPRF = *USER , 
    SRTSEQ = *HEX   
    BEGIN ATOMIC 
IF WC.CRTDT<200000 THEN
    UPDATE RAVONLIB . WC SET CRTDT = 1000000 + CRTDT ; 
END IF;
END  ;
```

I am getting an error that Variable CRTDT not defined or not usable.
What is the correct syntax in order to update CRTDT properly in case it is smaller than 200000?

Comment: Is this DB2 or another dbms?

Comment: Yes it is IBM DB2

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do an UPDATE to table WC in an **After** Update trigger on table WC?

Comment: Yes, there is a bug in the Mapics Browser application when a record is inserted/updated, the dates get a wrong format in one of the system tables. Therefore, I need to add a trigger to it so the field is getting formatted correctly.

Comment: Just curious, what variant of *date* format is the NUMERIC(7) column CRTDT storing, such that the algorithm shown makes sense? Or are perhaps the predicate and/or the arithmetic operation just contrived vs accurately representative?

Comment: 1[yy][mm][dd]: 1 represents year>=2000, yy for year, mm for month, dd for day

Comment: So the conspicuous inference to be made, is that the application is writing data for any dates from 2000-01-01 to 2019-12-31 as though they were 1900-01-01 to 1919-12-31. And to be sure, verification has been made, that the application is **not** making the same mistake for dates greater than or equal to 2020-01-01? Regardless; seems to be a critical flaw with the application; enough to justify getting a correction from the sfw provider.?

Comment: You got it right! I just changed 200000 to 1M so it will cover 2099 as well

Comment: You do know that integers are just four bytes in the DB?  You could store 20000101 in 4 bytes.  If your not going to use date data types like everyone else on earth at least you could be more efficient with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger.

Additionally, you need to be modifying the column value as it is inserted...you can't run an SQL `UPDATE` statement in a trigger on a row that was just inserted.

Lastly, you'd want a row trigger, not a statement trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER RAVONLIB.WC_TRIGGER 
    BEFORE INSERT ON RAVONLIB.WC 
    REFERENCING NEW AS new_row
    FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2ROW
    SET OPTION  ALWBLK = *ALLREAD , 
    ALWCPYDTA = *OPTIMIZE , 
    COMMIT = *NONE , 
    DECRESULT = (31, 31, 00) , 
    DFTRDBCOL = *NONE , 
    DYNDFTCOL = *NO , 
    DYNUSRPRF = *USER , 
    SRTSEQ = *HEX   
    BEGIN ATOMIC 
IF new_row.CRTDT<200000 THEN
    SET new_row.CRTDT = 1000000 + new_row.CRTDT ; 
END IF;
END  ;
```

Comment: I found the syntax solution for after insert but your solution is even more better and logic. Thank you

Comment: FWiW: An UPDATE statement *can* be run on a row just inserted [from within an AFTER INSERT trigger], and a FOR EACH STATEMENT trigger *could* be more desirable [and be defined to effect that UPDATE using the transition-table data] than a FOR EACH ROW trigger; that said, I agree with ***should*** as applied to all of: • using a BEFORE INSERT trigger • using a SET statement to update the specific incoming value in a BEFORE INSERT trigger • [thus] using a ROW trigger

Answer (score 1):

FWiW, mostly edification, as this is hardly an *answer* given my comment to the already *accepted answer*: As verified on v5r3, the following mimics the *statement* trigger from the OP to a logical conclusion; no idea who would even have a v4r5 system on which to test -- *¡holy smoke!*:

```
create table wc
( PKfld int not null
, CRTDT numeric(7)
, constraint WC_PK primary key (PKfld)
)             
;
CREATE TRIGGER wc_trg_ai                       
 After Insert on WC                            
REFERENCING NEW TABLE AS xt                    
FOR EACH STATEMENT  MODE DB2SQL                
SET OPTION COMMIT = *NONE                      
  BEGIN ATOMIC                                 
   update WC set WC.CRTDT = WC.CRTDT + 1000000 
   where WC.CRTDT<200000                       
     and exists ( select '1' from XT as xt     
                  where xt.PKfld = WC.PKfld ) ;
  END                                          
; -- semicolon as statement separator, not end of trigger-body
insert into wc values                                 
  (  1, '0000001'), (  2, '0200000'), (  3, '0000300')
, (  4, '0400000'), (  5, '0050000'), (  6, '0600000')
; -- per trigger dfn, the even-numbered key values will not see an UPDATE
select * from WC
; -- likeness of report from above query:
  PKFLD       CRTDT 
      1   1,000,001 
      2     200,000 
      3   1,000,300 
      4     400,000 
      5   1,050,000 
      6     600,000 
***  End of data  ***
```

Comment: Not fully clear why you had to reference xt and why it is a new table. Upvoted since it works fine for me too

Comment: The XT represents the Transition Table with a copy of all of the affected rows for an SQL insert, to which the SQL trigger needs to refer, to know what are the actual records in WC that need to be target of the UPDATE statement; what is shown is an AFTER INSERT, so the data was already inserted into WC, and the UPDATE statement must only update those rows which were inserted in the INSERT statement. If the WHERE EXISTS logic is removed, the action would update more data than what was inserted; perhaps fine for this particular scenario, but that effect would typically be viewed as *corruption*.